# AT+COPS=? returns "Operation not allowed"

Tags: gsm, telephony, cellular-network

I'm trying to get a modem with a Quectel BG96 chip connected to the internet from Linux, but every time I try to scan for carriers I get

```
AT+COPS=?
+CME ERROR: 3
```

after 60 or so seconds.  Why would scanning give me this error?